# Gradient of LSE due to fitting a vector field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, least-squares

Hi guys suppose a I have a family of functions

$$
\vec{f}(x_0,\ldots,x_{l-1} ; a_0,\ldots,a_{l-1}) = \vec{f}(\vec{x};\vec{a}) = (f_0(\vec{x};\vec{a}),\ldots,f_{n-1}(\vec{x};\vec{a}))^T
$$

And I have samples

$$
\left\{(\vec{x}_0,\vec{f}_0),\ldots,(\vec{x}_{m-1},\vec{f}_{m-1})\right\}
$$

And I wanted to find the vector $\vec{a}$ such that the error

$$
\epsilon^2(\vec{a}) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \left\lVert \vec{f}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})-\vec{f}_k \right\rVert^2
$$

Is minimum, assuming $\vec{f}$ is differentiable w.r.t. $\vec{a}$. I get

$$
\nabla_{\vec{a}}\epsilon^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \nabla_{\vec{a}} \left\lVert \vec{f}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})-\vec{f}_k \right\rVert^2=
2 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}  \left\langle \nabla_{\vec{a}} \vec{f}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a}),\vec{f}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})-\vec{f}_k \right\rangle =
{2 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}  \textbf{J}_{\vec{x}_k}(\vec{a})^T\left( \vec{f}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})-\vec{f}_k \right)}
$$

Where with $\textbf{J}_{\vec{x}_k}(\vec{a})$ I denote
$$
\textbf{J}_{\vec{x}_k}(\vec{a}) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial \vec{f}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})}{\partial a_0} & \ldots & \frac{\partial \vec{f}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})}{\partial a_{l-1}}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\nabla_{\vec{a}}f_0(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})^T \\
\vdots \\
\nabla_{\vec{a}}f_{n-1}(\vec{x}_k;\vec{a})^T \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm asking If I have messed up anything in this process.